# Why consistent hashing is better in handing hotspots than simple hashing?

Tags: scalability, sharding, system-design, consistent-hashing

I was reading System Design Interview An Insider’s Guide by Alex Xu, and it says that Consistent hashing is prevent uneven data distribution, but it doesn't explain why. So why exactly hash % n creates hotspots and why do virtual nodes from consistent hashing solve it?